# Scope work strangely in mapReduce of MongoDB for the purpose of producing cumulative frequency

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, scope

I have a collection called user, and I want to get cumulative frequency of number of users by date based on the _id field. The desired result should be something like that:

```
{ 
 {_id: 2013-12-02, value: 10}, //upto 2013-12-02 there are 10 users
 {_id: 2014-01-05, value: 20}, //upto 2014-01-05 there are totally 20 users

….
}
```

I try to get the above using the following mapReduce call:

```
db.user.mapReduce(
  function(){var date = this._id.getTimestamp(); 
             emit(new Date(date.getFullYear()+"-"+date.getMonth()+"-"+date.getDate()), 1)},
  function(key, values) {cum = cum + Array.sum(values); return cum},
  {out: "newUserAnalysis",
   sort: {_id: 1},
   scope: {cum: 0}})
```

But it seems that the cum variable reset to zero after the first return statement encountered in the reduce function. Why? Is there any other method to get what I want?

Many thanks.

Comment: Thank you Wizard for your answer. Now, I understand the problem lies at the reduce function. I resorted to calculate the cumulative values in the map function: 
{ var date = this._id.getTimestamp(); 
  cum += 1; 
  emit(new Date(date.getFullYear()+….., cum)
};

That seems work.

Thank you.

Comment: If less than 2 documents for every day in the collection, your `map function` works fine. But just supposing that there are 10 documents for a specific date (such as 2013-12-02), then the cumulative result will be 55, not 10 as expected. By the way, date.getMonth() returns 0~11, not 1~12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cum` should not be reset as it's a global variable in `map`, `reduce` and `finalize` functions during the whole mapReduce processing.

But `reduce function` has 3 requirements to be observed to assure processing correctly, particularly for bulky data handling since `reduce function` will be called repeatedly even on the same key. Normally the length of `values` in `map function` would not exceed 100. In a word, your design can't assure `cum` is called on the right sequence as you expect, which will produce incorrect statistics.

Following code for your reference:

```
// map and reduce per day then save to a collection.
db.user.mapReduce(function() {
    var date = this._id.getTimestamp();
    emit(new Date(date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-"
            + date.getDate()), 1);
}, function(key, values) {
    return Array.sum(values);
}, {
    out : "newUserAnalysis",
    sort : {
        _id : 1
    }
});

// Do accumulation one by one.
var cursor = db.newUserAnalysis.find().sort({_id:1});
var newValue = 0, first = true;
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    var doc = cursor.next();
    newValue += doc.value;
    if (first) {
        first = false;
    } else {
        db.newUserAnalysis.update({_id:doc._id}, {$set:{value:newValue}});
    }
}
```